# Java byte array to ECCPrivateKey - InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key, elliptic-curve, java-security

When I try to make ECC private key from byte array, I get exception mentioned below. I have public/private keys and out signed output from C library micro-ecc/uECC.h. C used secp192r1 curve. I am trying to verify data with C generated keys in Java.  How to convert byte array to private/public key?

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
byte[] kb = new byte[]{(byte)0x24, (byte)0xF4, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x16, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x90, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x51, (byte)0xF6, (byte)0x87, (byte)0x55, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x1A, (byte)0xA5, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0x55, (byte)0xDB};
X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(kb);
KeyFactory kf = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey remotePublicKey = (org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey)kf.generatePublic(ks);

java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328)
```

Also I have tried to use

```
KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
```

but it throws the same exception above.

```
KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
```

throws

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

or

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=116, too big.
```

Comment: Where did you get your byte array?

Comment: I have public/private keys and out signed output in C librarary  micro-ecc/uECC.h. I am trying to verify it in Java.

Comment: C used secp192r1 but I don't know if it necessary to provide it when loading public/private key in Java and how to do it.

Comment: When I generate key pair and create copies in Java, it works well.

Comment: @Justas If you generate correctly `EC` keypairs in *Java* using `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC")` and then you can parse it using `KeyFactory` methods. Then probably your `byte[]` keys are wrong or has some specific format. Also note that there is an error in your code (not related directly with the exception): `kf.generatePublic(ks)` can not be cast to `ECPrivateKey` so change it to: `(org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey)kf.generatePublic(ks);`.

Comment: It fails with keys generated using C librarary micro-ecc/uECC.h.

Comment: Found that C lib generated private key length is 24 bytes while Java - 125.

Comment: Interesting.  In theory, any integer by should be a valid ecc private key.  Really surprising that Bouncy Castle is complaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X509EncodedKeySpec(key)` or `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key)` constructors take private/public keys in encoded format. Unencoded key bytes can be converted this way:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp192r1");

ECPrivateKeySpec ecPrivateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(1, privateKeyBytes), spec); 

ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp192r1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
java.security.spec.ECPoint w = new java.security.spec.ECPoint(new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, 0, 24)), new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, 24, 48)));
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(w, params));
```