# Reading private key in java form bytes without encoding

Tags: java, cryptography

I have bytes of private key without encoding. Is there a way to read them to java.security.PrivateKey object? Reading through KeyFactory.generatePrivate() requires encoded key (for example PKCS8 encoded).
Could I read not encoded key? Or encode it to PKCS8 format?

My current code is:

```
byte[] keyBytes = hexToBytes("65462b0520ef7d3df61b9992ed3bea0c56ead753be7c8b3614e0ce01e4cac41b");
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));

public static byte[] hexToBytes(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

But it throws

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : Detect premature EOF
```

I got that key by next python script:

```
from secp256k1 import PrivateKey
import sha3

keccak = sha3.keccak_256()
keccak.update("secret".encode('UTF-8'))
digest = keccak.digest()
print("priv_key_test: " + PrivateKey(digest).serialize())
```

Comment: add code that you have tried to solve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436283/java-byte-array-to-eccprivatekey-invalidkeyspecexception-encoded-key-spec-not) for using EC-Algorithm with Java.